# Can there be an "insufficient explanation" auto comment on the review page for Low Quality posts?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

It seems like a lot of the low-quality posts are simply really short answers that would be fine if they explained why and how. Although it's easy enough to write a comment, it would be better if a template for this already existed, preferably one that's close to the mod notice for insufficient explanation.

The full mod post notice reads:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more information.

What I have posted as a comment in the review section:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.

The mod message that Yannis is referring to in his comment, the "citation needed" notice reads, in full:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

I would recommend a comment closer to below, since references to "article" don't make sense to me:

> This post does not cite any references or sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

Comment: Insufficient explanation.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the text of the post notice here, for everyone (and especially non mods) to get a better idea of what you are talking about. And, I'd like to see the "citation-needed" as a canned review comment as well...

Comment: @YannisRizos I've added the full mod notice, as well as what I've added as a comment a couple of times. I even added your citation notice comment.

Comment: Isn't that a message that's used on Wikipedia? I don't see a whole lot of things getting deleted on SO/SE just for being unsourced.

Comment: @PopularDemand It actually looks like a Wikipedia message, but it's a valid moderator notice that can be applied to questions or answers. And technically, it's true - you're supposed to back up claims with either experiences that demonstrate them or with (hopefully reputable) sources.

Comment: @PopularDemand Perhaps not on SO, but (for example) unsourced answers on Skeptics don't survive for long.

Comment: @YannisRizos Skeptics isn't a great example to use here. Facts are their whole deal.

Comment: @ThomasOwens yeah, ideally, but it doesn't seem to happen in practice. I vaguely remember getting into an argument with Robert Cartaino about this once. I was the one saying that unsourced things _shouldn't_ be allowed, and I got overruled.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well we use the post notices often on Programmers as well.